# CloudFormation CREATE_FAILED with error "Certificate ARN is not valid"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, hashicorp-vault

I am attempting to use the CloudFormation template for a new VPC and workload as provided within https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-hashicorp-vault/doc/hashicorp-vault-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf to create a vault cluster. However, I am seeing the following:

*VaultServerListener HTTPS CREATE_FAILED Certificate ARN '' is not valid (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 650c7ca1-0abe-4bae-9b30-d114c220423d)*

Comment: Can you post relevant part of the template? How did you setup your ACM certificates?

Comment: There's currently no ACM certificates on either AWS account and both produce the same error above.

Line 104:
      ACMSSLCertificateArn:
        default: SSL certificate ARN

The S3 URL with the template is here: https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-hashicorp-vault/templates/quickstart-hashicorp-vault-master.template

Comment: Did you deploy this template? quickstart-aws-acm-certificate.template.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your additional info, it seems that the **error originates** [here](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-hashicorp-vault/blob/891f3fbfa2f8290e1020e363fa179ee7f17d481a/templates/quickstart-hashicorp-vault.template#L467):

```
  VaultServerListenerHTTPS:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      Certificates:
      - CertificateArn: !If [ CreateDns, !GetAtt "ACMCertificate.Outputs.ACMCertificate", !Ref ACMSSLCertificateArn ]
```

Your comments indicate that there is **no ACM certificate** setup. However, if you look at the code above, an ACM certificate **must** be provided.

Either you create your **own ACM certificate** and provide its arn in `ACMSSLCertificateArn` parameter, or let the template **create one** for you using [this](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-aws-acm-certificate/blob/fc050e1df4f19857c76e3bb9cebaec49d025fa7d/templates/quickstart-aws-acm-certificate.template.yml) template.

For the ACM certificate, you need to have a **custom domain**, for example setup in Route53.

Answer (score 21):

Make sure that the certificate ARN

- is in the same region as the load balancer,
- has status "Issued" (not "Expired").

Try creating the load balancer without the certificate arn first, then add a listener with the certificate using the AWS Console web interface.

Comment: Worked for me. The certificate wasn't in the same region as the load balancer. I had to create another certificate with the same DNS name in the same region and then it worked fine.

Comment: I didn't know this was not valid until now, but you're right

Answer (score 1):

From only Error looks like you are using the wrong *Cloudformation* resource. The Type of an `application` load balancer is `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`. It has *V2* on the end.

And the one you are probably using is `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer` and that creates a classic load balancer.

The error you are getting is due to the difference in the return values for `Ref` function between classic LB and `application` LB.

But if you post your code I can help more :D